# Software to access Windows hardrive from Android phone via USB

Tags: windows, android, file-management, usb

When I plug my phone into my Windows 7 laptop, it automatically lets me access the phone's SD card.

What I want to do is the reverse: when I plug in via USB, let me access the PC's files via USB (so not over WiFi) on the phone's file manager. I currently use ES explorer, but anything will do.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a [DLNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) server on your Windows computer. (In Linux, you can install [uShare](http://ushare.geexbox.org/).)

Then you can use any DLNA application in Android to browse the DLNA share exposed on your Windows computer.

DLNA is typically used to stream media files, but you will be able to browse directory listing as well.